# Post to facebook from WP App with images

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone

I'm using this article to post messages to facebook from my app in windows phone.
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Integrar_o_Facebook_numa_aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Windows_Phone

It works fine, but my question is that is only possible to post text, but I want post text with image and link, like this

```
var postParams = new
{
name = "Facebook SDK for .NET",
caption = "Build great social apps and get more installs.",
description = "The Facebook SDK for .NET makes it easier a",
link = "link",
picture = "link_to_image"
};
```

This code is used in facebooksdk

Is possible do the same with facebook utils ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send request with parameters below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me/feed?name={0}&message={1}&caption={2}&link={3}picture={4}&access_token={5}
```

All values (except access_token) should be encoded with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`. You can remove any parameter if you don't need to post it.